# Как с помощью php/mysql выбирать шаблон, соответствующий странице?

Tags: php, mysql

Господа!

Ищу мудрого совета. Ситуация следующая: пишу небольшой сайт на php + mysql. Всего на сайте планируется использовать 3-4 различных типа страниц, например: главная страница, страница услуги, страница галереи, страница юзера. Выглядят все они по-разному, и для каждой из них я создал свой шаблон.

Вопрос в том, как с помощью php определять, какой именно шаблон нужно загрузить для текущей страницы? Пока что моей фантазии хватило только на то, чтобы формировать определенную структуру урлов, парсить ее, и исходя из этого подгружать шаблон. Т.е. выглядит это примерно так: если в url встречается /service/что-нибудь/, то один шаблон. Если /gallery/что-нибудь/, то другой. Если вообще ничего не встречается, то это главная страница.

Опыта в php немного, но мне кажется, что такой подход отдает излишней кривизной. Как можно реализовать подгрузку нужного шаблона без привязки к url? Если я хочу создать страницы site.ru/some-page-1/ и site.ru/some-page-2/, и чтобы они использовали разные шаблоны, как мне быть? Может быть, добавить какие-то дополнительные поля в БД? Но опять же, доступ к ним осуществляется только после того, как страница определилась с шаблоном.

Куда копать?

Заранее благодарен за любые дельные советы!

Comment: посмотрите код CMS - или фреймворка и сделайте также

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> добавить какие-то дополнительные поля в БД

Самое, на мой взгляд, лучшее решение. Создать таблицу, в которой будет храниться тип страницы. В таблице, где хранятся страницы добавит поле с id типа страницы.

После этого на основании типа страницы можно будет подставить шаблон (в т.ч. автоматически).

Comment: Мне приходила в голову такая мысль, но додумать ее до конца не получилось.

Для каждого урла, какого бы типа он ни был, загружается один и тот же файл index.php. Внутри этого файла уже решается, какой шаблон в него подгрузить. И вот тут ступор. Для наглядности: при загрузке site.ru и site.ru/service/ исполняется один и тот же файл index.php. И никакие поля в БД на этом этапе не позволяют php решить, какой шаблон для них загружать.

Может быть, такой подход с одним файлом, который выбирает шаблон, вообще принципиально неправильный? Если это так, то направьте на путь истинный :)

Comment: "никакие поля в БД на этом этапе не позволяют php решить, какой шаблон для них загружать" - позволяют. `if($page->type == 'post'){ require 'posttemplate.php';}`. Надеюсь, принцип понятен.

Answer (score 0):

я для таких целей использую $_GET переменные в ссылках.
а в index.php обработчик типа -

```
if(isset($GET['somevar'])){
    $page = '/sometTemplate.php';
    include (__DIR__.'/pages/index.php'); 
    die();
}
```